# Slave node not starting in hadoop cluster. Not able to understand the log file

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, hdfs

[image: Slave node log]

When i start hadoop cluster then after doing jps i am not able to see datanode. Below is the log from slave node. I am not getting what is the error. It was working fine before the ec2 instance re-started.

Comment: The slave node is not able to contact the server on 172.31.44.75 at port 8025. Check if the daemon is running on port 8025 and also check if there are any firewall issues.

Comment: I tried changing the port but its giving me the same error on every port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add exception in security group in ec2. Here is the answer that helped.
[Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance)