# AWS: EC2 in public subnet can't ping EC2 in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping, subnet

Very strange:

- The public and private subnets are in the same VPC.
- EC2 in private subnet uses a security group that opens up 0-65535 to 0.0.0.0/0. So does its network ACL.
- I can RDP from the **public** subnet EC2 into the **private** subnet EC2.
- I can ping between **private** subnet EC2 instances.
- But I just can't **ping** from the **public** subnet EC2 to the **private** subnet EC2.

Comment: Can you disable the windows firewall and try. It is possible the windows firewall is not allowing ICMP traffic.

Comment: Why do you want to Ping? Isn't the ability to RDP proof enough of connectivity?

Comment: I don't have to ping, but not able to ping is an indication of something wrong - I also can't mount a private subnet file gateway from a public EC2 instance. If the EC2 instance is in the same private subnet then I can mount the file gateway. So something is not right.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out why: the network ACL doesn't have an outbound allowance for ICMP.