# Unable to ping EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm very fresh to AWS and have tested to launch an instance as shown below:

[image]

And below is the `security group` with the `inbound` rules attached

[image]

My problem is I couldn't ping this server. May I know if I understood something wrongly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to new Inbound Rule for it :

**Type:** Custom ICMP rule

**protocol:** Echo Request

**port:** N/A

**source:** your choice (My IP To be able to ping from Your IP)

Also Just an **FYI** You Should Never Show Details in Question (like Instance tag , Public IP )

Comment: I agree that it's often best to redact certain information from questions, but I don't think instance-id itself is typically considered sensitive.  On the official AWS forums, it's fairly common for AWS personnel to ask customers for the ID of an instance or other resource.

Answer (score 1):

This is applicable to windows machines only:

Opening the port solves the problem partially for windows VM.

With `Windows 2019 server`, I had to configure the firewall of the VM as well. Post the firewall change (window firewall), I was able to ping.