# nodejs websockets connection from localhost works but remote doesnt

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm running a simple websocket server in nodejs

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ host: '0.0.0.0', port: 13000 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

        console.log("new connection");

        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
                      console.log('received: %s', message);
                    });

        ws.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('error', e);
        });

        ws.on('close', function(e) {
                console.log('close', e);
        });

        ws.send('something');
});
```

I can connect to the server using:

```
s=new WebSocket('ws://localhost:13000')
```

and everything is fine. But if I try to connect from another computer:

```
s=new WebSocket('ws://serveripaddress:13000')
```

The server shows

```
new connection
close 1006
```

So I know that the client connects, but it then immediately disconnects. I am totally lost here, don't know how to diagnose my problem. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

These scenarios work:

- two ec2 instances: works
- two linux VMs communicating over a host-only network: works

And these fail:

- windows host machine and VM (host only network): fail
- an ec2 instance and one of my VM's: fail

Here's the weird part, if I make a simple socket server using 'net', ALL scenarios above work! So it seems like its still a networking issue (since websockets work in some scenarios) but it is a networking issue specific to websockets (because socket server works where websocket doesnt)!

I dont have access to the firewall that my windows host machine is on so if that's the issue then I'm stuck. But I will try this all on a different host machine where I have access to the firewall.

But if it was the firewall, I would except it to work between the windows host and the VM because they are on their own virtual network...

Comment: What kind of client are you using?

Comment: also nodejs, both are on linux

Comment: Personal Firewall on your server computer?  Anti-virus?  Does ping work reliably from client computer to server computer?

Comment: If the server has a stateless firewall, make sure you open inbound for port 13000, and outbound 1024-65535.

Comment: well i was running the server on an ec2 instance and the client on a VM. I'm not able to ping the server machine from the client, not sure why(followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance)). I'm working on setting up another VM so i'll be communicating between VMs on the same host machine... i'll share my results

Comment: @chuck1 were you able to solve it? I am having same issue, but with heroku...

Comment: @Empus Were you able to solve it?