# Remote Desktop in AWS

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just launched a new windows server 2016 virtual machine from EC2 Management Console.
I tried to connect RDP from my desktop (MAC OS) it is not connecting, and even the machine is not pingable from public IP and public domain name.

please the machine is up and running and the from the security group i enable the inbound rules for port 3389

Answer (score 0):

You would need the [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-8-0/id715768417?mt=12), the default RDP app will not work and for the ping, you need to enable ICMP protocol in the Security group and then open the windows firewall. Here is a detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42777521/2244717)

Comment: still nothing happen, is the policies applied immediately or need to restart server

Comment: i install the above client and applied the security policies to the group