# Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance with public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping

I cannot ping my EC2 instance with which has a public IP associated with it.  Before posting here, I read [Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance).  It didn't help:

Here's how I have things set up:

I created a new Amazon Linux t2.micro instance using all the defaults.

After creation, it didn't have an IPv4 Public IP in the EC2 | INSTANCES | Instances.

So I went to EC2 | NETWORK & SECURITY | Elastic IPs, and clicked the Allocate Elastic IP address button.  After the Public IPv4 address column showed an address, I clicked Actions | Associate Elastic IP address.

I went back to EC2 | INSTANCES | Instances, and the IPv4 Public IP column shows the address I just created.

Still cannot ping.

So I went to EC2 | NETWORK & SECURITY | Security Groups, clicked the link for the security group associated with the instance and added an inbound and outbound rule like so:

```
All traffic          All        All       0.0.0.0/0 
All ICMP - IPv4      ICMP       All       0.0.0.0/0
```

Still cannot ping.

So I went to VPC | Internet Gateways, clicked the Create internet gateway button, selected the defaults, and then attached the internet gateway to the VPC which is associated with the instance.

Still cannot ping.

So I went to VPC | SECURITY | Network ACLs, Edit Inbound and Edit Outbound rules.  This is what I have for both:

```
Rule #   Type              Protocol       Port Range      Source       Allow / Deny
100      ALL Traffic       ALL            ALL             0.0.0.0/0    ALLOW
101      All ICMP - IPv4   ICMP (1)       ALL             0.0.0.0/0    ALLOW
```

Still cannot ping.

What else is missing to be able to ping?  Yes, I can ping other hosts on my network... just not to AWS and the public IP address listed for that EC2 instance.

Comment: Are you getting permission denied or it just times out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it is worth mentioning that there should generally be no need to every modify the Network ACLs. They can be used for special purposes (eg creating a network DMZ), but otherwise just leave them at their default values.

I should also mention that using `PING` generally isn't worthwhile because it can be blocked by many network configurations. Rather than trying to get Ping to work, you should try to get whatever it is that you *actually* want to work, to work. For example, if you wish to SSH into the instance or use it as a web server, try to get them working rather than Ping.

Here are the things that would be necessary to get PING to work:

- The EC2 instance is launched in a **public subnet**. This is defined as:

  - A subnet that has a **Route Table** entry that directs `0.0.0.0/0` to an **Internet Gateway** (You did not mention the Route Table in your Question.)
- A **public IP address** associated with the instance (either at launch, or by adding an **Elastic IP address** afterwards, as you did)
- A **security group** that permits inbound ICMP traffic from your address (or wider, such as `0.0.0.0/0`)
- An **operating system** on the instance that is configured to respond to PINGs (this will typically be on by default, but it is the OS that responds to the request)
- A network from which you request the Ping that also **permits such traffic to flow**. (Some corporate networks block such traffic, so you could try it from an alternate network such as home, work or via a tethered phone.)

So, based on the information you have provided, you should confirm that the **subnet** has a **Route Table** that points to the **Internet Gateway**.

Comment: That was it... thanks!!!  The subnet does have a route table which does have a internet gateway... But, when I clicked Edit Routes to see what was in there, the route table only had the local traffic in it (10.10.0.0/24).  I had to add a public route.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Network ACL, add inbound rule for ICMP IPv4 - allow 0.0.0.0
- Go to Security Group. Pick the SG name you created for your EC2 instance (mine is launch-wizard-1). Add inbound rule for ICMP IPv4 - allow 0.0.0.0

Vwa-lah, I can ping.

Note:  I'm using Amazon Linux (free tier t2.micro)