# Instances on the same subnet I can't ping from one to the other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

good morning, how are you? I have a VPC with a subnet that contains 2 instances, which use the same security group and the same routing table, I can ping the internet, I can ping the external ip from one to the other, but via **internal IP they do not communicate** what Can be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance)

Comment: Could be a security group not allowing traffic (default is deny everything) or a network ACL that restrict traffic (but the default is allow everything)