# AWS Instance won't accept pings despite security group settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, ping, aws-security-group

We spun up a server in AWS and when attempting to ping its public IP, the ping request times out.

I have created a security group to enable port 22, enabled ICMP traffic with echo request, and verified that other security group configurations will work. No luck- pings time out.

I'm thinking there has to be a parent setting somewhere that's blocking all ICMP regardless of instance settings- something on the main account.

Anyone have ideas?

[image]

Comment: It's a Windows instance presumably. I think that Windows firewall blocks inbound ICMP requests by default. So you also need to allow ICMP through the Windows firewall. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981796/cannot-ping-aws-ec2-instance).

Comment: Have  you checked your NACL? Also have you made sure this instance has internet access  through IGW? Update the question with more details about networking etc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys- it was the Windows firewall auto blocking ICMP traffic- took off this restriction and things worked fine.

Good to know- future viewers of this ticket, if your instance is Windows- ICMP needs to be enabled in AWS security groups and put on Instance, AND you need to log into the instance itself and configure the Windows firewall to allow ICMP traffic.